# Replace OOTB page layout with custom page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, custom, 2016, ootb

I having multiple pages which are created using OOTB page layouts. I want to replace those with custom page layouts. Is there any way to replace the dependency of page layouts with corresponding pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page layout of any page using PowerShell or CSOM approach.

Please find below CSOM approach (it's a pseudo code):

```
string _newPageLayoutUrl= "new page url";
string newPageLayoutDescription ="new desc";

    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    List pagesList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
    var allItemsQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

    ListItemCollection items = pagesList.GetItems(allItemsQuery);
    clientContext.Load(items);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem item in items)
    {
        var pageLayout = item["PublishingPageLayout"] as FieldUrlValue;
        // This will return the Full URL of Page Layout - https://.....aspx

        try
        {
            item.File.CheckOut();
            item["PublishingPageLayout"] = new FieldUrlValue() { Url = _newPageLayoutUrl, Description = newPageLayoutDescription };
            item.Update();

            item.File.CheckIn("comment", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
            item.File.Publish("comments");
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```